# opencv2/tracking.hpp: No such file or directory on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu, tracking

i am working on tracking project so i needed tracking.hpp library. and every time i try to compile the project. it says fatal error: opencv2/tracking.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include

so i do some search and i found out that i have to download opencv_contrib and build it. and those are the the command line i used to build opencv_contrib.

"cd /home/pixar/Downloads/OpenCV/opencv-3.2.0/build"

"cmake -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH= /home/Yasd/Downloads/OpenCV/opencv_contrib-master/modules .."

then
 "make -j5"

but the same error appears. so did i miss something?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you forgot to run **make install** command. Go to your build directory and **make install**
Your path to tracking.hpp is wrong. Replace it with actual path

```
#include "opencv2/tracking/tracking.hpp"
```

Also make sure you've added opencv to your project. With cmake it can be done like that:

```
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
include_directories(OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIR)
```

[Source](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/tracking/include/opencv2/tracking/tracking.hpp)

Comment: still the same error and btw i need tracking.hpp not traker.hpp.

Comment: I've updated my answer, changed traker with tracking & it seems like you forgot to run make install after make -j

Comment: Try to search for this header manually within you installation directory (not build directory). Should be somewhere around /usr/include/opencv.  Are you sure that build and install finished without errors?

Comment: Also double check that you added opencv to your project's include path. Updated my answer with cmake example